# Do you have to disprove one side of an "either/or" to use the other side?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, proof-theory

I've got an abstract HW question asking me to write a 2 column proof with a bunch of axioms and theorems that are either assumed or previously established.  One of them is:   if x then either y or z.

My question is, do I first have to disprove one side in order to use the other side?  In other words, do I have to prove that "if ~z then ~x" is false before I can use "if ~y then ~x"?

Neither my textbook nor my teacher's notes are being very helpful in this.

[EDIT]
Here is the problem and the solution manual's "solution" which I'm not sure really works.  (I simplified in my original question with x,y,z, here are the letters they used)

[image]

Comment: the [Converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_(logic)) is not necessarily true.

Comment: "If x then (y or z)" does not imply "if ~y then ~x"; indeed when x=T, y=F and z=T, the first holds but the second doesn't. You may get a more helpful answer by listing the axioms and hypotheses you are given and what you are asked to prove.

Comment: Maybe useful [Disjunctive syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_syllogism): if we have an "alternative" $P \lor Q$ and we have *disproved* one of them, i.e. we have proved $\lnot P$, we can safely conclude with the other one: $Q$.

Comment: Simliar to [Modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens): if we have proved a *conditional* $P \to Q$ and we have *disproved* the consequent, i.e. we have proved $\lnot Q$, we can safely conclude disproving the antecedent, i.e. having $\lnot P$.

Comment: The "link" is that $P \to Q$ is equivalent to $\lnot P \lor Q$.

Comment: The proof does not work; from Ax.1, Ax.2 and Th.3 alone, we cannot conclude with $p \to q$, because we can check via truth table that Ax.1, Ax.2, Th.3 $\nvDash p \to q$.

Comment: Th.3 is $r \to (x \lor y)$. Contraposing it: $(\lnot x \land \lnot y) \to \lnot r$. Thus, in order to derive $\lnot r$, we need both $\lnot y$ **and** $\lnot x$.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, my "answer" to this problem that I will turn in will be a page long explanation on why this problem can't be done as stated.  :)

BTW, does ¬ mean the same thing as ~, not?  so ¬z = ~z = not z?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but it sounds like you *want* to have 'if not y then not x', and you are given 'if x then (y xor z)', and you are wondering whether you would need to show that 'if not z then not x' is false in order to get to 'if not y then not x'.

Yes, you are right!  From 'if x then (y xor z)' alone you certainly cannot get 'if not y then not x', for if x is true and y is false and z is true, then the first statement is true, but the second is not. However, if you can show that 'if not z then not x' is false, then that will rule out the counterexample just given. Indeed, this would mean that you cannot have z if you have x, so then you must have y whenever you have x or, what is the same thing: 'if not y then not x'.

Comment: Pretty sure this answers my question, which means the solution manual is wrong.  *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

So the provided proof does *not* work, but you *can* derive $p \rightarrow q$ from the axioms and theorems. I am not sure what rules and principles you have, but here is a proof sketch:

1. $p$ Assumption
2. $\neg y$ MP Axiom 1, 1
3. $\neg z$ MP Theorem 1, 1
4. $\neg q$ Assumption
5. $r$ Axiom2, 4
6. $x \lor y$ MP Theorem 3, 5
7. $x$ Disjunctive Syllogism 2,6
8. $q \lor z$ MP Theorem 2,7
9. $z$ Disjnctive Syllogism 4,8
10. $\bot$ Contradiction 3,9
11. $q$ Reductio ad absurdum 4-10
12. $p \rightarrow q$ Conditional Proof 1-11

Comment: @DanaHill As I said, I don't know the specific rules of the proof system you work with. For example, can you do proof by contradiction in your system?  And if so, how does that work?  Can you maybe post the inference rules that are given to you?